# How to change data of a NSCollectionView with buttons

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, swift3, nscollectionview

I have data that is coming in via JSON and I was able to switch the data in my collection view based off some logic.  If I am logged in it shows one set of data and if I log out it shows another set of data. But now I want to change the data of my collection view based on button pushes.  I have two buttons.  One shows "All Products" and the other shows "Installed Products" How can I incorporate button pushes to switch between my data?

**CollectionView Logic**

```
extension ViewController: NSCollectionViewDataSource, NSCollectionViewDelegate, NSCollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{


func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    let prefs:UserDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
    let isLoggedIn:Int = prefs.integer(forKey: "ISLOGGEDIN") as Int

    if (isLoggedIn == 1) {


    return installedArray?.count ?? 0
    }

    return productsArray?.count ?? 0
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, itemForRepresentedObjectAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> NSCollectionViewItem {

    let prefs:UserDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
    let isLoggedIn:Int = prefs.integer(forKey: "ISLOGGEDIN") as Int

    if (isLoggedIn == 1) {


    let item = collectionView.makeItem(withIdentifier: "Installed", for: indexPath) as! Installed

        item.buildProduct = installedArray?[indexPath.item]

    return item
    }

    let itemB = collectionView.makeItem(withIdentifier: "test1", for: indexPath) as! test1

    itemB.buildProduct = productsArray?[indexPath.item]

    return itemB

}
```

**Buttons**

```
@IBAction func allAppsPushed(_ sender: Any) {

    let prefs:UserDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
    let isLoggedIn:Int = prefs.integer(forKey: "ISLOGGEDIN") as Int

    if (isLoggedIn == 1) {




    }else{


    }


}

@IBAction func installedPushed(_ sender: Any) {

    let prefs:UserDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
    let isLoggedIn:Int = prefs.integer(forKey: "ISLOGGEDIN") as Int

    if (isLoggedIn == 1) {



    }else{



    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling `collectionView.reloadData()` in your button methods. That will cause the collectionView to completely reload it's data, and since your `isLoggedIn` flag has changed states, you should load different data.

Comment: I understand what you're saying but my data only changes if I am logged in or not.  I don't want it to rely on if I am logged in or not.  I need to to change purely based off the button push.  I tried what you said and nothing changes.  It just reloads the same data that is already there and doesn't switch.

Comment: So make your buttons change an instance variable in your view controller, and then in the collection view's `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` method, use the value of that instance variable to decide what to display in the collection view.

Comment: would you happen to have an example of something like this?  I have a solution that is working but I am curious about your method as well.

Answer (score 0):

I moved my isLoggedIn outside of my class to make it a global variable and in each button i set the variable first and then checked my logic and now it switches between my data!

```
@IBAction func allAppsPushed(_ sender: Any) {

    isLoggedIn = 1

    if (isLoggedIn == 1) {

        colView.reloadData()

    }else{

    }
}


@IBAction func installedPushed(_ sender: Any) {

    isLoggedIn = 0

    if (isLoggedIn == 1) {

        colView.reloadData()

    }else{

        colView.reloadData()

    }
}
```